# Find all links that have an href that begins with a specific text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capybara, capybara-webkit

I need to find all links on the page where the `href` begins with `../items/`. For example:

```
<a href="../items/some-link">Some link title</a>
<a href="../other-link">Other link title</a>
<a href="../items/some-link-2">Some link title 2</a>
```

I tried the following Regexp, but it is not working:

```
review_links = page.find_link('a')[:href] == '%r{^../items/\w+}'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What structure does `page.find_link('a')[:href] ` return? Testing that something is *equal to* a regular expression is not what you want. Obviously your link isn't going to be a regular expression. You want to test that it *matches*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a CSS-selector to find all links that have an `href` attribute starting with a text:

```
review_links = page.all('a[href^="../items/"]')
p review_links.map(&:text)
#=> ["Some link title", "Some link title 2"]
```

Note that the `href^=` means an `href` attribute starting with.

Answer (score 4):

The `:link` selector takes an `:href` option that accepts a regex to match against.  So if you're looking for a single result you could do

```
page.find_link(nil, href: /regex to match against/)
```

in Capybara 2.7 the initial nil is required to indicate you aren't using the normal locator that would be passed to find_link (link text, etc), in Capybara 2.8 when released it won't be necessary.  Note: the regex is matched against what node['href'] returns which in most drivers is the href property (as opposed to attribute) and is therefore normalized to be the full url the link refers to - http://example.com/abc/def even though the attribute in the document may just be set to /abc/def.  If you are actually looking for more than one result then you can do

```
page.all(:link, nil, href: /regex to match against/)
```

If instead you are just checking that a certain number of matching links (3) exist it would be

```
expect(page).to have_link(nil, href: /regex to match/, count: 3)
```